# Change name and Application icon when starting via Automator

Tags: automator, dock, icon, emacs

I have a script called gnus:

```
#!/bin/bash
open -n -a Emacs --args --name Mail --title Mail --no-desktop --no-splash --funcall gnus
```

which I call via Automator

```
Run Shell Script - ~/bin/gnus
```

Now I the name next to the icon in the dock, when the program is running, is still Emacs and thew Emacs icon (as when starting Emacs.app directly.

I would like to have the gnus icon and the name as Gnus as I want to pin it to one specific Desktop.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The issue here is that you are running Emacs.app just with arguments to it

Answer (score 1):

You could make a copy of the application bundle:

```
cp -r /Applications/{Emacs,gnus}.app
defaults write /Applications/gnus.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleExecutable gnus
defaults write /Applications/gnus.app/Contents/Info.plist CFBundleIdentifier my.gnus
echo $'#!/bin/bash\n/Applications/gnus.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs --name Mail --title Mail --no-desktop --no-splash --funcall gnus' > /Applications/gnus.app/Contents/MacOS/gnus
chmod +x /Applications/gnus.app/Contents/MacOS/gnus
```

I changed the bundle identifier because spaces assignments are per bundle identifier. It also makes the application have a different preferences file.

I don't know how to change the application name.

Comment: To change name normally rename the executable and the App however emacs is a complex build so that might not work